# Passing argument from method using super

Tags: python, oop, superclass

I'm trying to set an argument role='r' under a method called getphone. It's working ok under **init** using super but I can't figure out how to do it under another method

The role is to set the permission level for the api that is running

this code is working

```
PATH = 'home_drive_'
PLATFORM = 'Linux_'
ITEM = '_PC'

class Credential:
    def __init__(self, *, path, platform, role='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.role = role
        self.username_file = path + platform + role


class AXL(Credential):
    def __init__(self, *, item, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(role='rw', **kwargs)
        self.item = item

    def getphone(self):
        self.role = 'r'
        return self.username_file + self.item

    def writephone(self):
        self.role = 'rw'
        return self.username_file + self.item

    def statusphone(self):
        self.role = 'rwx'
        return self.username_file + self.item

reg1 = AXL(path=PATH, platform=PLATFORM, item=ITEM)

print(reg1.getphone())
print(reg1.writephone())
print(reg1.statusphone())
```

under the class AXL, I want to move the role='r' under the method getphone

I've tried this and it's working but i don't understand why i need to put the path and platform.

```
PATH = 'home_drive_'
PLATFORM = 'Linux_'
ITEM = '_PC'

class Credential:
    def __init__(self, *, path, platform, role='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.role = role
        self.username_file = path + platform + role


class AXL(Credential):
    def __init__(self, *, item, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.item = item

    def getphone(self):
        super().__init__(path=PATH, platform=PLATFORM, role='r')
        return self.username_file + self.item

    def writephone(self):
        super().__init__(path=PATH, platform=PLATFORM, role='rw')
        return self.username_file + self.item

    def statusphone(self):
        super().__init__(path=PATH, platform=PLATFORM, role='rwx')
        return self.username_file + self.item


reg1 = AXL(path=PATH, platform=PLATFORM, item=ITEM)
print(reg1.getphone())
print(reg1.writephone())
print(reg1.statusphone())
```

a sandbox can be found [here](https://repl.it/@louis_philippedescamps/Passing-argument-from-method-using-super?language=python3&folderId=)

Comment: If i understand correctly, you can set `self.role = 'r'` inside `AXL.final`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can't (at least not in any way that conforms to conventions and that will be easy to debug). `role` is required to initialize a `Credential` instance so it must be provided when initializing an `AXL` instance.

Comment: It's not clear what your ultimate goal is. Do you want to replace the attribute `username_file` (currently initialized in `__init__`) with a method that computes a value using a given role when called? (Which would convert `role` from an attribute of an instance to simply an argument to `final`.)

Comment: for example, i would have AXL.getphone, AXL.writephone and AXL.statusphone.

getphone's role is read-only (r)
writephone's role is read/write (rw)
statusphone's role is read/write/execute (rwx)

Depending of the role, the credential would return the username/pwd to use

thank you

Comment: @chepner, this is what I'm trying to do
https://repl.it/@louis_philippedescamps/Passing-argument-from-method-using-super?language=python3&folderId=

Comment: OK, so `role` isn't something inherent in an instance of the class; it's really just a something determined by which method you are calling.

Answer (score 1):

There's no one role associated with an instance; rather, the role is associated with a method *called* by the instance. Try this.

```
PATH = 'home_drive_'
PLATFORM = 'Linux_'
ITEM = '_PC'

class Credential:
    def __init__(self, *, path, platform, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.username_file = path + platform


class AXL(Credential):
    def __init__(self, *, item, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.item = item

    # "Private" method used to implement the other phone methods
    # You could inline this if you want.
    def _phone(self, role):
        return self.username_file + role + self.item

    def getphone(self):
        return self._phone('r')

    def writephone(self):
        return self._phone('rw')

    def statusphone(self):
        return self._phone('rwx')

reg1 = AXL(path=PATH, platform=PLATFORM, item=ITEM)

print(reg1.getphone())
print(reg1.writephone())
print(reg1.statusphone())
```

Comment: that's working but not sure how I can use it in my real script that I copied [here](https://repl.it/@louis_philippedescamps/api)

Comment: It looks like anything involving `role` should be a method that builds the path on the fly using a `role` arugment, rather than being an attribute of an instance. Or, you should have a lot more subclasses, each of which *does* have a fixed role.

Comment: Hi, what about doing it like [this](https://repl.it/@louis_philippedescamps/method-by-roles). thanks

Answer (score 0):

`super()` will let you access the parent class scope. You can access any method from it in the form `super().method(args)` in python3, with python 2 the format is `super(YourClass,self).method(args)`.

Calling `__init__` on the parent for each method doesn't seems to be right from the OOP perspective. You are reinitializing the parent object during its life time. If you want to set role from the parent you can simply use `self.role = ...`. Any method on parent accessing `self.role` will see the modification.